# Outlook Rest api, how to delete a contact photo

Tags: vba, image, photo, outlook-restapi

I can add or change contact photos with Set contact photo:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts('{contact_id}')/photo/$value
```

But how can I DELETE a contact photo ??

Comment: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/photo-rest-operations#set-user-photo) don't mention anything about deleting. Have you tried to set a contact photo to nothing? Or change it to, say, a 1x1 white pixel .jpg? A placeholder "person" image would seem appropriate, no?

Comment: Apparently you cant as mentioned [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e7f95ec-c308-493f-91ac-91dc553692d9/delete-contact-photo-or-user-photo-through-the-rest-api?forum=Office365forDevelopers)

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, i saw this also.
Mathieu, ok i can send an dummy Pic, i don't tried ist yet.

Wondering. also online, there is no way to delete a photo, only add and change.